# How to change an html external link with tooltips into link_to in rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Apologies I am a noob to all this, I think I have searched for my question but can't find a solution.
Anyway,
I have the following line of code from a purchased theme:

```
<a href="#" class="header-btn header-btn-sm" data-hover="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="link me on linkedin"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin header-icon"></i> </a>
```

I want to turn it into a rails link_to, I can handle the class aspect, but not sure how to keep the icon and manage the tooltip js?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to("#", {"data-hover" => "tooltip"}) do %>  
  <i class="fa fa-linkedin header-icon"></i>  
<% end %>
```

Read more about [link_to](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to)